# How To Get Application In Sleep Mode

Tags: android, sleep

How to do hold application get in sleep mode android programmatically.

I used this function but it gave me crash.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            pm.isDeviceIdleMode();
```

please help me to find out this problem.

Comment: could you post logcat output?

Comment: No virtual method isDeviceIdleMode()Z in class Landroid/os/PowerManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.os.PowerManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar) –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's what are you looking for [Power Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep%28long%29).

Add this `<permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/>` in your manifest too.

**Update**

Add this permission in your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: No virtual method isDeviceIdleMode()Z in class Landroid/os/PowerManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.os.PowerManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)

Comment: have you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK`" /> in your manifest?